# Why 2:240 is written in quran?

Tags: quran, naskh

> Sahih al-Bukhari, 4530
> • Sahih al-Bukhari, Vol. 6, Book of Prophetic Commentary on the Qur'an, Hadith 53
> • Sahih al-Bukhari, Book of Prophetic Commentary on the Qur'an, Hadith 53
>
> > Narrated Ibn Az-Zubair:
> >
> > **I said to 'Uthman bin 'Affan (while he was collecting the Qur'an) regarding the Verse:-- "Those of you who die and leave wives ..." (2.240) "This Verse was abrogated by an other Verse. So why should you write it? (Or leave it in the Qur'an)?" 'Uthman said. "O son of my brother! I will not shift anything of it from its place**."

> > Chapter 2 verse 240
>
> *Those of you who die leaving widows should bequeath for them a year’s maintenance without forcing them out.1 But if they choose to leave, you are not accountable for what they reasonably decide for themselves. And Allah is Almighty, All-Wise*.
> Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran
> That

**Why this verse is in quran even thou it was abrogated and why did Uthman wrote it in quran**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of abrogation:

1. The ruling is abrogated but the recitation is not
2. The recitation is abrogated but the ruling is not
3. Both the recitation and ruling is abrogated

This verse and many other verses fall into the first type. So they are part of the Quran. The recitation of the Quran was reviewed by the Prophet with Gabriel (see e.g. [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3554)), it was not upto Uthman to choose what would go into it and what would be left out.

Note that there are some who consider that the verse is not abrogated at all even in ruling, see [Tafsir al-Tabari](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/tabary/sura2-aya240.html#tabary).

Comment: Brother can you give me English me an English commentary. Because I can't understand Arabic

Comment: http://m.qtafsir.com/Surah-Al-Baqara/Ayah-2:240-was-abrogated

Comment: Thanks brother for the English tafseer